# How to update a specific row in SQLite in android

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I have a `database` having two columns `COLUMN_ACCOUNT` and `COLUMN_PASSWORD`, where the table looks like

```
COLUMN_ACCOUNT       COLUMN_PASSWORD

facebook               a
gmail                  b
twitter                c
```

Now I want the `row` with name `COLUMN_ACCOUNT = facebook` have the `COLUMN_PASSWORD` changed from `a to x`. The resulting table will look like :

```
COLUMN_ACCOUNT       COLUMN_PASSWORD

facebook               x
gmail                  b
twitter                c
```

I have tried using this function :

```
public int modifyCredentials(String account,String newPass){

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,newPass);
    String whereClause=COLUMN_ACCOUNT + " =?";
    String[] whereArgs=new String[]{account};
    int update=db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,whereClause,whereArgs);
    return update;
}
```

where the `parameters` `account` has the value `facebook` and `pass` has the value `x`, but it did not work. There is no problem with the parameters, I have double checked it and I think the problem lies in the `sql query`. Can you please help me out with the required `sql query`. Thank you :)

Comment: Print out the string after you do variable substitution.  The problem should be obvious.  Then, learn how to put parameters into queries, so you are not munging query strings, introducing potential syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.  (In case you don't get it, there is no space before `SET`.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff , Sir I have edited my question and also my `function`. Can you please look into it?

Answer (score 0):

Read this page carefully: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html.
It provides you everything you need.

Also you should not use `db.execSQL(...);`. Android provides you more convenient methods to insert, query, update and delete rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add spacing in all the string literals you have as they might be the ones causing the issues you are experiencing.

Especially between the TABLE_NAME and " SET " so they can be explicitly different words

Answer (score 0):

Try using void

```
public void modifyCredentials(String account, String newPass)
{

SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,newPass);
String whereClause=COLUMN_ACCOUNT + " =?";
String[] whereArgs=new String[]{account};

db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,whereClause,whereArgs);
db.close();
}
```